# Vue sets Undefined to properties whose value should be 0 or false

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, vuex

I fetch an object in my vue application using axios. The object's structure is supposed to look like this:

```
result: [
    {
     entityState: 0,
     id: 0,
​​​​     name: "All",
     isActive: false
   },
   {
     entityState: 0,
     id: 1,
​​​​     name: "Phone",
     isActive: false
   },
   {
     entityState: 0,
     id: 2,
​​​​     name: "Computer",
     isActive: false
   },
   {
     entityState: 0,
     id: 3,
​​​​     name: "All,
     isActive: true
   },
]
```

which I save to my vuex store like this:

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    stocks: [],
    categories: [],
  },
  mutations: {
    ......

    updateCategories(state, result) {
      console.log('from updatecategories: ', result);
      state.categories.splice(0, state.categories.length, ...result);
    },

   ......
  },
  actions: {

    .......

    fetchCategories(context) {
      axios.get('https://localhost:5001/categories').then(response => {
        console.log('this is response', response);
        const { result } = response.data;
        context.commit('updateCategories', result);
      });
    }, 

  ........

  },
});
```

which I call from my components like this:

```
export default {
  name: 'ProductsCatalogue',
  data() {
    return {
      stocks: {},
    };
  },
  components: {
    SideBar,
    ProductCard,
  },
  beforeMount() {
    this.$store.dispatch('fetchCategories');
  },
 .....
};
```

and then use in another component like this:

```
<template>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
      <ul class="sidebar-nav">
        <li
          v-for="(category, index) in categories"
          v-bind:key="category.id"
          :class="{ active: category.isActive }"
          @click="
            {
              makeActive(category, index);
            }
          "
        >
          <a href="#">{{ category.name }}</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'SideBar',

   .......

  data() {
    return {
      categories: this.$store.state.categories,
    };
  },

   .......
};
</script>
```

but when the data gets to my app, it seems like vue replaces the values of each property of the object with getters and setters which should in turn return the actual values when they are needed. It looks something like this (when console.logged ):

```
result: (6) […]
​​​
0: Object { id: Getter & Setter, name: Getter & Setter, entityState: Getter & Setter, … }
​​​
1: Object { id: Getter & Setter, name: Getter & Setter, isActive: Getter & Setter, … }
​​​
2: Object { id: Getter & Setter, name: Getter & Setter, isActive: Getter & Setter, … }
​​​
3: Object { id: Getter & Setter, name: Getter & Setter, entityState: Getter & Setter, … }
​​​​​​
length: 4
​​​
<prototype>: Array []
```

The problem here is that when I store this data to my vuex store and access it from other parts of the app it shows something like this:

```
result: [
    {
     entityState: undefined,
     id: undefined,
​​​​     name: "All",
     isActive: undefined
   },
   {
     entityState: undefined,
     id: 1,
​​​​     name: "Phone",
     isActive: undefined
   },
   {
     entityState: undefined,
     id: 2,
​​​​     name: "Computer",
     isActive: undefined
   },
   {
     entityState: undefined,
     id: 3,
​​​​     name: "All,
     isActive: true
   },
]
```

when it actually should return something like this:

```
result: [
    {
     entityState: 0,
     id: 0,
​​​​     name: "All",
     isActive: false
   },
   {
     entityState: 0,
     id: 1,
​​​​     name: "Phone",
     isActive: false
   },
   {
     entityState: 0,
     id: 2,
​​​​     name: "Computer",
     isActive: false
   },
   {
     entityState: 0,
     id: 3,
​​​​     name: "All,
     isActive: true
   },
]
```

That is to say that it returns "undefined" for properties whose values should actually be 0 or false.
I've been trying to find out why this happens in vue but there seems to be no explanation in the vue documentation so I think there must be something I'm getting wrong in my code. I need someone to please help me figure this out.

Thanks.

Comment: Something is wrong here `state.categories.splice(0, state.categories.length, ...result);`. What does `console.log('result', result)` print? Also, I haven't touched vue in a while, but IIRC, your dispatched action `updateCategories` should call a mutator, and not try to mutate the state itself.

Comment: My dispatched action does exactly call the mutator 'updateCategories' with a payload. It does not try to mutate the state itself. console.log('result', result) shows exactly what I described above.....I'm really out of my wits on this one.

Comment: Hey man!, if someone's answer helped you please mark it as an accepted answer or at least give them a points. We are not here just to give you a time understanding your question and make solutions with just saying tank you and  not  giving points, please be good.

Answer (score 1):

It's not undefined, you are just accessing only those data where your categories are not ready that's why it says undefined isactive data right ? To solve that, put first a condition to prevent loading the component while your vuex is preparing your categories. see code below

```
<ul class="sidebar-nav" v-if="$store.state.categories.length > 0">
        <li
          v-for="(category, index) in categories"
          v-bind:key="category.id"
          :class="{ active: category.isActive }"
          @click="
            {
              makeActive(category, index);
            }
          "
        >
          <a href="#">{{ category.name }}</a>
      </li>
 </ul>
```

Or, use watcher to update your categories when vuex is already ready.

```
watcher: {
    '$store.state.categories' : {
         this.categories = this.$store.state.categories
    },
}
```

Comment: I have tried this and its still not working. I dont think the issue is from the data not being ready since it gets all the other data that are not "false" or "0". The issue is based on the "falses" and "0s" value returning undefined. I dont understand why it is behaving like that.

Comment: do a getters for that. Nothing wrong with that and I already encountered that situation, it is undefined yet the value is correct right ?

Comment: The issue with doing getters is that they only evaluate once and I need this to be as reactive as possible. I've tried your updated code and it shows a different result altogether, I'll tweak it some more and see if it'll work out.

Comment: then why not make a watcher for that ? I updated my answer

Comment: Bingo! Thats it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206590/discussion-between-ken-maduka-kenny-and-qonvex620).